# Using the eval command to create a command alias

Tags: regex, bash, eval

For the life of me I cannot get the bash script to execute the alias command to set the hostname of a workstation the alias name to the WOL (Wakeup On Lan) equivalent command. I figure there must be an issue with quoting somewhere that I am missing.

```
#!/bin/bash

WOLHosts=`nvram get wol_hosts`

WOLList=($(echo "$WOLHosts" |  grep -o '[A-F0-9]\{2\}:[A-F0-9]\{2\}:[A-F0-9]\{2\}:[A-F0-9]\{2\}:[A-F0-9]\{2\}:[A-F0-9]\{2\}=[^=]*=[0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*' ))

if [ "${#WOLList[@]}" -gt 0 ]
then
for Match in ${WOLList[@]}
do
    Command=`echo "$Match" |  sed -r "s/([A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2})=([^=]*)=([0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*)/alias \2='\/usr\/sbin\/wol -i \3 \1'/"`
    Name=`echo "$Match" |  sed -r "s/([A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2})=([^=]*)=([0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*)/\2/"`
    Com=`echo "$Match" |  sed -r "s/([A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2})=([^=]*)=([0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*)/\/usr\/sbin\/wol -i \3 \1/"`
    alias $Name="$Com"
    eval $Command
    echo "$Command"
done
fi

exit 0
```

Here is some sample data and output that I am currently receiving with the script:

Input (into WOLHosts):

```
00:1F:D0:26:72:53=Justin-PC=192.168.1.255 00:16:17:DD:12:7B=Justin-HTPC=192.168.1.255 00:1C:25:BC:C3:85=justinlaptop=192.168.1.255
```

The output produced by the vi WOecho "$Command" is:

alias Justin-PC='/usr/sbin/wol -i 192.168.1.255 00:1F:D0:26:72:53'
alias Justin-HTPC='/usr/sbin/wol -i 192.168.1.255 00:16:17:DD:12:7B'
alias justinlaptop='/usr/sbin/wol -i 192.168.1.255 00:1C:25:BC:C3:85'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you appear to be running this as a script, your current shell will not receive the aliases -- the aliases will disappear then the bash process driving the script ends.

Try: `. script.sh` or `source script.sh`

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of the scope of bash scripts. I have more reading to do.

P.S. For anyone using this script remove the exit 0 as the context of the exit is the current session, not the bash script